# How to solve when value 1 using e.getMessage() in Java

Tags: java, exception

Anyone know why Exception().getMessage return to 1? What does it mean? I have tried to find the answer but nothing found, thank.

Comment: Use `e.printStackTrace()` when an exception occurs.

Comment: some code somewhere in your app, or a library you are using, is doing:  `throw new Exception("1")`.  When you throw, you can put whatever text you like in there.  No idea why somebody would just put "1".  `e.printStackTrace()` might tell you who did it

Comment: Please provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to produce the problem.

Comment: @MrSpoon Just like the message for a `NullPointerException` is `"null"`, the message for many index based exceptions like `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` is the index.

Comment: @Kayaman ah ok, nice to know - thanks!

Comment: I am using logger to read error from server, so cannot put printStackTrace into log.

Comment: @MrSpoon looks like `AIOOBE` is smarter (not sure if it was always this way) so it doesn't just print the index only. However there are some exceptions (like `NPE`) that don't have a proper message.

Answer (score 1):

Use `e.printStackTrace` instead of `e.getMessage()` in case of exception. It will display all the information required to debug the issue, whereas printing only the message of the exception doesn't tell you almost anything.

If using a logger, use the form that accepts an exception/throwable, usually of the form `logger.error("Custom error message", e);`, and the stacktrace will be printed.

Comment: Inside logger it should be something like `logger.error("Error occurred", e)`.

Comment: Thank, bro. I got it.

Comment: No problem brutha, stay fresh y'all.